# How to access ActionMode's close button in AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android, android-actionmode

I have an ActionMode and I'd like to access its close button within AppCompatActivity.

The theme for my Activity is:

```
<style name="NewAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

This is what I do to call the close button:

```
  Integer doneButtonId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_mode_close_button", "id", "android");
```

and `doneButtonId` is null as my debugger indicates.

What do I need to do to access the close button , as I need a reference to attach a click listener ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation and it works properly in my code. Hope it helps you.

```
int doneButtonId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_mode_close_button", "id", "android");
View doneBtn = MainActivity.this.findViewById(doneButtonId);
doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // You can finish this by setting ActionMode.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is what I have done already and does not work. For additional info, the ActionMode's 'tick' button is now replaced by the 'backward arrow' which I find suspicious.  Did you use a startSupportActionMode to display your ActionMode (which is what I am using) in which case is "action_mode_close_button", the right string to use ?